# How to clear the entire console window?

Tags: c#, console, window

I am making a console window RPG, yet I'm having problems clearing the entire console window. Is there a way for me to clear the entire console window with one command?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use the [Clear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.clear.aspx) method:

```
Console.Clear();
```

Comment: I hate the way Microsoft build these cryptic APIs that make it so frackin hard to find the command you need!

Comment: use visual studio for the things @James Gaunt