# How to clear the terminal inside your c# program?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm creating one of my first projects in visual studio code, and my game has a lot of text in it. I wanna know how to clear the terminal when the player goes into the next "level", so they don't see all the text fill up the screen from before.[What I want to clear while running the program] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtXYt.png)

Comment: Console.Clear();

Comment: By terminal, do you mean `Console`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear the entire console window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238232/how-to-clear-the-entire-console-window)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Console.Clear()` method

Answer (score 0):

You can use Console.SetCursorPosition(Int32, Int32) to set Cursor to 0,0 and redraw it without screen blink.

If you want simple clear Console.Clear() does the job, but it will take time to redraw Console again.